# No logical volume groups found, LVM stuck at boot

Tags: boot, lvm

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit). Long story short, I've compiled a custom kernel and now I'm running into some issues with my encrypted hard drive.

When I boot my machine and attempt to start the new kernel, it starts loading and reports:

```
Reading all physical volumes, this may take a while ...
   No Logical Volume Groups found
   No Logical Volume Groups found
```

While compiling the new kernel, I've taken my current kernel configuration (from `/boot/config-$(uname-r)` as the base so all modules that were in use during the compilation should also be available with the new kernel.

I'm a little stumped at where to start debugging. A colleague suggested I take a look at the `initrd`-images for both kernels. I've unpacked both images but have had little luck in determining what might be wrong. The size is quite different:

The new initrd:

```
emikkva@slartibartfast:/tmp/15$ ll init.img
-rw-rw-r-- 1 emikkva emikkva 18278400 july 18 18:01 init.img
```

And the old one:

```
emikkva@slartibartfast:/tmp/15$ ll ../13/init.img 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 emikkva emikkva 77744640 heinä 18 18:02 ../13/init.img
```

But the only differences are (both images unpacked):

```
emikkva@slartibartfast:/tmp/15$ diff -r . ../13
Binary files ./init.img and ../13/init.img differ
Only in ../13/lib: firmware # This might be a problem?
Only in ../13/lib/modules: 3.13.0-32-generic
Only in ./lib/modules: 3.15.0-rc8+
```

grub boot parameters are identical for both kernels. Using the old kernel works just fine.

I understand I've got little information to offer here but I will of course update the question with anything that might be relevant according to comments and answers.

EDIT:

lsblk output:

```
emikkva@slartibartfast:~$ lsblk
NAME                           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                              8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                           8:1    0   243M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                           8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5                           8:5    0 238,2G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt (dm-0)          252:0    0 238,2G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root (dm-1)   252:1    0 222,3G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (dm-2) 252:2    0  15,9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

pvs:

```
emikkva@slartibartfast:~$ sudo pvs
  PV                     VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  238,23g    0
```

dmsetup ls --tree:

```
emikkva@slartibartfast:~$ sudo dmsetup ls --tree
ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (252:2)
 └─sda5_crypt (252:0)
    └─ (8:5)
ubuntu--vg-root (252:1)
 └─sda5_crypt (252:0)
    └─ (8:5)
```

EDIT 2:

Checking the configuration file as per suggested by @derobert:

```
emikkva@slartibartfast:~/airlied-linux$ grep -i 'config_crypto_aes\|config_dm_crypt\|config_crypto_xts\|config_crypto_sha256\|config_crypto_sha512' .config
CONFIG_DM_CRYPT=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_XTS=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_SHA256_SSSE3=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_SHA512_SSSE3=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_SHA256=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_SHA512=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_X86_64=m
CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL=m
```

The configuration for the new kernel was identical, except for that `_SSE3` -ending options, they were commented out.

Current crypto-algorithm in use seems to be `aes-xts-plain64` according to the output of `dmsetup table sda5_crypt`.

Comment: What's your encryption set up---is the encryption below LVM (e.g., the partition the physical volume is on is encrypted) or above LVM (e.g., the logical volume is encrypted)? If the former, can you confirm crypto setup succeeded?

Comment: Probably dumb question, but why a custom kernel?

Comment: @derobert I'm not sure. It's the default settings from the ubuntu installation process.

Comment: @msvalkon That's *probably* encryption under LVM then, but not sure. `lsblk`, `pvs`, or `dmsetup ls --tree` from the working kernel should let us know.

Comment: @derobert edited the outputs to the question.

Comment: OK. You have crypto beneath LVM. So it'd appear that LVM failed because the crypto isn't up yet. Are you sure you have all the crypto stuff enabled in your kernel build?

Comment: @FaheemMitha It's because I've got a dell docking station at work, and two monitors. The kernel and video driver is unfortunately unable to distinguish the two monitors connected to the docking station (you can use the two monitors with a combined 3840x1200 resolution though). There's a bug fixed kernel patch available and also a new xf86 driver. Using these the problem should be fixed.

Comment: @derobert unsure, i assumed that *everything* that is currently loaded would be in place for the new kernel as well. I have the kernel `.config` available if that helps.

Comment: I'd suggest looking further up in the boot messages for errors. Something to explain why it didn't set up crypto. Did it prompt you for your passphrase?

Comment: Did not prompt for a passphrase, just outputs the error message. Will dig further and see if I can get any relevant stuff out.

Comment: I think the relevant config options are `CONFIG_DM_CRYPT`, `CONFIG_CRYPTO_XTS`, `CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES`, `CONFIG_CRYPTO_SHA256`, and `CONFIG_CRYPTO_SHA512`. Presuming those are the algorithms in use (`/etc/crypttab` will say, but double-check it for secrets before posting, though it shouldn't have any).

Comment: Actually, it may not be in /etc/crypttab. But `dmsetup table sda5_crypt` from the working kernel will give the algorithm in use. That should look something like `0 11714560 crypt aes-xts-plain64 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0 253:1 0` Note the long string of 0's, that's a placeholder for the key. If yours shows something other than 0's there, DO NOT POST IT. `aes-xts-plain64` is the algorithm in my case.

Comment: @derobert thanks for the suggestions, I will test these asap!

Comment: @derobert I've edited some more output to the question. Seems like the configuration is identical.

Comment: for the record; I got this error because my custom kernel build was missing the NVME module so couldn't see the disk. http://askubuntu.com/a/719947/79266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the reason was that I had compiled the kernel like so:

```
make oldconfig
make -j6
sudo make install
```

I was wondering why my previous (official ubuntu repo) initrd was 28m in size while the new one was 8m. I had not installed the modules!

Doing

```
sudo make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 modules_install 
sudo make install
```

fixed it. Now the HD crypto is initialized correctly and LVM does not break. Thanks to @derobert for helping out.

Comment: BTW: since you're running a Debian-derived distro, you can probably use `make deb-pkg` (instead of `make install`/`make modules_install`) and then install the resulting packages.